# Django select_related queryset in template not rendering

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a simple view like so:

```
def classticker(request):
    tickermodel = Tickers.objects.all().select_related('subsector_fk')
    form = TickerForm()
    return render(request, 'feeds/main.html', {'v': 10, 'form': form, 'tickermodel': tickermodel})
```

tickermodel is successfully returning a queryset with all of the fields in the Tickers table and the Subsector table (through the subsector_fk field).  This includes the fields 'ticker', 'company_name' and 'subsector' that I'm using in the template below.

When I render my template and iterate through the tickermodel queryset I cannot seem to access fields that are coming from the Subsector table.  Below tic.ticker and tic.company_name are rendering as expected but tic.subsector is not.  I have no idea why??

My template looks like this:

```
<table class="tbllist">
<tr><th>Current Tickers</th></tr>
{% for tic in tickermodel %}
<tr>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="myclass" value="{{tic.ticker}}"/></td>
  <td class="selectable" data-tik="{{tic.ticker}}"><span class="uppercase">{{ tic.ticker }}</span> - {{ tic.company_name }}</td>
  <td>{{ tic.subsector }}</td>   <!-- <<<< this will not display >>>>> -->
</tr>
{% endfor %}

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select_related` doesn't somehow make the related fields available in the main model; it doesn't change the structure at all. Your related fields are still available by following the foreign key field. The thing that select_related does is to make that more efficient by doing a JOIN query so that the related objects are already populated.

You haven't shown your models so I can't tell what the actual FK field is, but you would need to do something like `tic.subsector_fk.subsector`.

Comment: Thank you!  so simple.. was pulling my hair out.  I was thinking queryset creates a new object with all of the data, but apparently that's not what is going on.